# Errors installing Matplotlib - clang

Tags: python, xcode, macos, matplotlib, clang

I've tried to install Matplot lib but I'm still struggling to get past errors.

I've installed numpy and psipy but have the following error when I use easy_install (there is a similar error with pip).

And yes, I've installed the command line tools in Xcode in a bid to solve the 'gcc-4.2 not found' problem.

```
pymods ['pylab']
packages ['matplotlib', 'matplotlib.backends', 'matplotlib.backends.qt4_editor',          

'matplotlib.projections', 'matplotlib.testing', 'matplotlib.testing.jpl_units',     

'matplotlib.tests', 'mpl_toolkits', 'mpl_toolkits.mplot3d', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid',     

'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1', 'mpl_toolkits.axisartist', 'matplotlib.sphinxext',    

'matplotlib.tri', 'matplotlib.delaunay', 'pytz', 'dateutil', 'dateutil.zoneinfo']
warning: no files found matching 'KNOWN_BUGS'
warning: no files found matching 'INTERACTIVE'
warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
warning: no files found matching '__init__.py'
warning: no files found matching 'examples/data/*'
warning: no files found matching 'lib/mpl_toolkits'
warning: no files found matching 'LICENSE*' under directory 'license'
gcc-4.2 not found, using clang instead
In file included from src/ft2font.cpp:3:
src/ft2font.h:16:10: fatal error: 'ft2build.h' file not found
#include <ft2build.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: The problem is that `gcc-4.2` is not available in your path, it tries to use `clang`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: OK, thank you, much appreciated. I'm still very new to this path stuff, can I fix it manually? If so, how? And is there a good reference online so I can get to grips with it.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: this has not to do with a missing compiler, even though that ultimately gives the error message. See my answer below: it can't find a header file.

Comment: The gcc one is a bit more critical as even with the libs you won't get far if it can't find gcc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recently had this issue as well, but I was using pip.  If you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed you can solve it by running the following commands:

```
brew install freetype
brew install libpng
brew link freetype
pip install git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git#egg=matplotlib-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

theres actually an easier way! First see if X11 libraries are installed (ls /usr/X11/include)

If they aren't you may need to install X11

If they are then a simple fix is this:

```
cd /usr/X11/include
sudo ln -s freetype2/freetype
```

Basically for some reason its looking for the freetype library at /usr/X11 and its actually in the subfolder in freetype2. Odd - but it does then compile this way.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following and it worked for me

```
sudo apt install libfreetype6-dev
pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing freetype2, or at least the development version. It's looking for `ft2build.h`, which is a freetype2 header file.

You can either try installing [freetype2](http://www.freetype.org/index2.html) from source, or just a package manager like macports, fink or homebrew to install it (for package managers, make sure you pick the development version if that's available).

But if you are going the route of package managers, you could also install matplotlib that way. And there may be binaries for OS X that include freetype2, so that may be even easier than installing from source.

The reason easy_install and pip don't install freetype2 for you, is that it's not a Python package.

== Correction ==

freetype2 should be available, not just where easy_install or pip expect it. On my Mac, I can ft2build.h in /usr/X11/include. So, you'll need to set the `CFLAGS` variable to that directory (and probably `LDFLAGS` to /usr/X11/lib`) to get the installation working. Now, with easy_install and pip, I'm not 100% sure how to do that. Try e.g.

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/X11/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/X11/lib easy_install matplotlib
```

Or, just download the matplotlib source, adjust `setup.py` and build it yourself.